# Computer froze when I punched the desk

Tags: freeze, crash, desktop-computer, components

I don't really have a habit of punching things and I've only really had this issue one time about a week ago, but I'd just like to see if there's a clear reason why this could have happened.

A few days ago I was playing a very heated match of CS:GO with my friend and I was the last one alive during the round, but then I got killed. Due to the heat of the moment, I just punched the desk a bit (read: a lot) harder than I intended to. The desk vibrated a bit, and my PC froze. I could hear the sound looping in my headphones (a very tight loop, basically just noise) and the screen was frozen on the last picture. I had to hold the on/off button for a few seconds to turn it off completely.

At first I got kind of scared about this, thinking that I might have broken something (while at the same time I was laughing about the funny way it happened), but then I rebooted and it worked fine up until today.

I realized it might be best to clear the issue, even if it seemed to have no consequences, so that I might prevent future problems that can happen if I neglect this.

---

My PC is custom-built. It has [a huge heat sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjz4p.jpg) attached to the CPU and the motherboard, which stand vertically (so the heat sink is leaning out on the side). The GPU comes horizontally out of the motherboard and it also attached to the case. The power supply is a 750W brick which resides at the bottom of the case. The RAM (16GB) sits on the motherboard, covered by the heat sink (again, because it's huge).

Here's a picture:

[image: Photo of my PC]

I know it's probably hard to say "Component X was the cause", but I'm just wondering if the symptoms I've mentioned sound familiar to you, also considering the leaning tower of heat sink I have in my pc that could have vibrated and somehow detached the CPU in the socket.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually a heatsink becoming dislodged is nearly impossible, but if it did, the CPU should shut down. Maybe put the tower on a more stable surface or orient it horizontally. And stop punching things!

Comment: Yeah, it's not really hard to nudge even if I push it with my finger, so it seems to at least be attached firmly.

Comment: Depending on how hard things were shaken, its definitely possible you made the hard drive headers crash into the moving platters. Or it could have caused just enough of a hiccup to stall the OS. Also make sure with that heatsink everything is seated properly. I've seen some heavy heatsinks bend motherboards over long periods of time / heat!

Comment: Could have shaken the HDD or gfx or the fan in the PSU or.. really anything. I'd say move the tower.

Comment: Does the PC freeze like that when the reading heads of a hard drive crash? Is there also a way to check for broken/damaged sectors in my HDD?

Comment: **CHKDSK /R c:** from admin command prompt.  You will have to say **yes** to do on next reboot.  This process could take longer than 3 hours depending on how many files you have and how big your hard drive is... plan accordingly.  Reboot, when you have time, and let it run to completion.

Comment: @Raystafarian Depending on the CPU, it may not shutdown due to a dislodged heatsink. AMD is pretty bad about this.

Comment: @kobaltz - Its safe to assume the system in question uses an Intel CPU based on the motherboard color and the heatsink being used.

Comment: @kobaltz  AMD has dislodged heatsinks??  I have had more than 12 AMD systems and the heatsink has never dislodged or been loose in anyway.  Every time I have upgraded the CPU the seal has been tight.

Comment: @cybernard I'm not saying that is a trait of AMD. The Original Post said that they had punched their desk and the computer froze. I was making a point to Raystafarian where a poorly cooled AMD processor has a tendency of overheating rather than shutting down.

Comment: Didn't read anything but title.... Loosened a connection to something on MoBo, GPU, RAM chips, etc. when you hit it. Power off, unseat and reseat every single connection and component you can including everything.